# UIBarButtonItem doesn't appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have an issue, when the view is loaded, it will load the UIBarButtonItem, but then i have to set it to nil in "mostra_filtro_btn", but then again in "load_map" i have to set it, but it doesn't show up.
Here is my code:

```
//
//  FirstViewController.m
//  House Finder
//
//  Created by Giovanni Poli on 12/05/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Giovanni Poli. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MapViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "Reachability.h"
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FiltroViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize filtro_controller,overlay_filtro_counter,mappa_controller;



-(void)load_map{
    NSLog(@"load_map");
    [mapView removeFromSuperview];
    [mappa_controller.view removeFromSuperview];
    [filtro_controller.view removeFromSuperview];

    UIBarButtonItem *Button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filtro" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(mostra_filtro_btn:)];
    [Button setTitle:@"Filtro"];
    [Button setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = Button;
}

- (id) init{
    filtro_controller = [[FiltroViewController alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:filtro_controller.view];
    [self addChildViewController:filtro_controller];
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.title = @"Mappa";
    self.navigationItem.title = @"House Finder";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = FALSE;
    UIBarButtonItem *Button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filtro" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(mostra_filtro_btn:)];
    [Button setTitle:@"Filtro"];
    [Button setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = Button;

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *content = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:content options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSArray * json_all = [json objectForKey:@"results"];






    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-40)];
    mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
    mapView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    NSDictionary * temp;
    for (id object in json_all) {
        temp = object[@"titolo"];
        annotationCoord.latitude = [object[@"lat"] floatValue];
        annotationCoord.longitude = [object[@"lon"] floatValue];
        MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
        annotationPoint.title = object[@"titolo"];
        annotationPoint.subtitle = object[@"agenzia"];
        [mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
    }

    [mapView showAnnotations:[mapView annotations] animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}


- (IBAction) mostra_filtro_btn: (id)sender{
    NSLog(@"mostra_filtro_btn");
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;


    filtro_controller = [[FiltroViewController alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:filtro_controller.view];
    [self addChildViewController:filtro_controller];
}







- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViews viewForAnnotation:annotation{
    if (annotation == mapViews.userLocation) return nil;
    MKPointAnnotation * temp = annotation;
    MKAnnotationView * m = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"casa"];
    m.canShowCallout = YES;
    m.enabled = YES;
    m.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    NSString * icon_file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",temp.subtitle];
    m.image = [UIImage imageNamed:icon_file];
    return m;
}


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{
    NSLog(@"overlay prezzo");

}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: Try:
`self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

// Or

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];`

instead of 

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil; `

in your mostra_filtro_btn Action method

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to nil the navigation item so it will hide where ever you want

```
[self.navItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
[self.navItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
```

Comment: the issue is that doesn't appear when i set it in "load_map" method it disappear without problem

Answer (score 1):

Try first create the UIButton then put it into the navigation button as follow

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 44.0f, 30.0f)];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popVC) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]     initWithCustomView:backButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't post this as a comment here is what I think is missing inside load_map:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       NSLog(@"load_map");
    [mapView removeFromSuperview];
    [mappa_controller.view removeFromSuperview];
    [filtro_controller.view removeFromSuperview];

    UIBarButtonItem *Button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filtro" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(mostra_filtro_btn:)];
    [Button setTitle:@"Filtro"];
    [Button setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = Button; 
})
```

This is a possible solution till you try it. If you share the code from where you call load_map it would be great!

Cheers!

Comment: from another view
    MapViewController * map_view_controller = [MapViewController alloc];
    [map_view_controller load_map];

Comment: So this bar button isn't being added since the view has not layed out its subviews. It is only after `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubview`' call we should update the frame of the view controller

Comment: Why are you allocating a new instance of the view controller. As far as I have understood, You are just adding a view of another view controller on click of the `mostra_filtro_btn`. In `FiltroViewController` call the `MapViewController` as `[(MapViewController *)self.parentViewController load_map]`. Also maintain `FiltroViewController` as a @property of `MapViewController` to avoid re allocating and creating a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfect, as you said you are adding button with method `mostra_filtro_btn :` in `viewDidLoad` method, and on click of button, button from navigation bar set to nil.

But the problem is that, from nowhere you calls `load_map` method. You need to call this method once the button gets nil, to get it back with `load_map` method.

May you get it.

Enjoy Coding!!

Comment: I call the load_map method in another view of another class

Comment: MapViewController * map_view_controller = [MapViewController alloc]; [map_view_controller load_map];

Comment: So is it possible that, this method get called once user delete right bar button, and view already loaded? I think the method not called after view load. Is it printing Log when you called `[map_view_controller load_map];`?